# Pandas Panel Data - Lagging variables by taking into consideration the year gap

Tags: python, pandas, finance, panel-data

I am working with a large panel data of financial info, however the values are a bit spotty. What I am trying to achieve is to lag certain variables of my data frame, so that the values at time t-1 are aligned to those at time t.

Normally, to lag a variable, I would use `df.groupby('tic')['investments'].shift()` , however this would clearly give the wrong answer as a possible missing year in my df could result in the wrong time lag. To give you an idea, the df looks something like this (just giving an example):

```
       datadate    fyear    ticker    tot_a    debt
0    31/12/1998     1998      AAPL   188.92   32.44
1    31/12/1999     1999      AAPL   197.44   56.09
2    31/12/2002     2002      AAPL   268.13   89.72
3    31/12/2003     2003      AAPL   278.06   96.32
4    31/12/2004     2004      AAPL   288.35   94.21
5    31/12/2005     2005      AAPL   312.23   84.21
6    31/05/2008     2008      TSLA    45.67    2.56
7    31/05/2009     2009      TSLA    38.29    2.90
8    31/05/2010     2010      TSLA    42.89    4.89
9    31/05/2011     2011      TSLA    56.03    3.78
10   31/05/2014     2014      TSLA   103.45   12.33
..       ...            ..       ..
```

What I am looking for is a piece of code that would allow me to understand (for each individual firm) if there is any gap in the data, and lag specified variables at t-1 if not gap occurs or insert NaN if there is one. Just like this:

```
       datadate    fyear    ticker    tot_a    debt
0    31/12/1998     1998      AAPL      NaN     NaN
1    31/12/1999     1999      AAPL    188.92  32.44
2    31/12/2002     2002      AAPL      NaN     NaN
3    31/12/2003     2003      AAPL    268.13  89.72
4    31/12/2004     2004      AAPL    278.06  96.32
5    31/12/2005     2005      AAPL    288.35  94.21
6    31/05/2008     2008      TSLA       NaN    NaN
7    31/05/2009     2009      TSLA     45.67   2.56
8    31/05/2010     2010      TSLA     38.29   2.90
9    31/05/2011     2011      TSLA     42.89   4.89
10   31/05/2014     2014      TSLA      NaN     NaN
..       ...            ..       ..
```

I hope that the questions makes sense!

Thank you in advance guys :)

Answer (score 0):

```
for i in range(1, len(df)):
if (df.loc[i, 'ticker']==df.loc[i-1, 'ticker']) & (df.loc[i, 'fyear']==df.loc[i-1, 'fyear']+1):
    df.loc[i, 'tot_a_1'] = df.loc[i-1, 'tot_a']
else:
    df.loc[i, 'tot_a_1'] = None
```

Here is my code.